# HC-05 AT commands Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, command, at-command

I am trying to simulate the AT commands of HC-05 Bluetooth module on Proteus 8, using Arduino micro-controller, and after entering the commands I get no response here is the code I used:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(5, 6); // RX | TX
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Enter the command:");
    BTSerial.begin(38400);       // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        // read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        // say what you got:
        Serial.print("I received: ");
        Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        if (BTSerial.available())    // read from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
            Serial.write(BTSerial.read());

        if (Serial.available())     // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
            BTSerial.write(Serial.read());

    }
}
```

Comment: That's C++, I'm assuming?

Comment: You aren't sending `incomingByte` to the Bluetooth module.

Comment: So if i shall change the incomingByte =Serial.read() to incomingByte=BTSerial.read() that would be the correction is that right ?

Comment: Are you holding the button down on power up to put in AT command mode?